# User-defined literals

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

In ["User-defined literals"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) on cppreference.com, what does it mean by this?

> b) otherwise, the overload set must include either, but not both, a raw literal operator or a numeric literal operator template. If the overload set includes a raw literal operator, the  user-defined literal expression is treated as a function call `operator "" X("n")`

Please, I need a simple example that illustrate this text.

Comment: Examples are in the same page... See the box after point 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned long long operator "" _w(unsigned long long);
unsigned operator "" _u(const char*);

int main() {
    12_w; // calls operator "" _w(12ULL)
    12_u; // calls operator "" _u("12")
}
```

A little bit changes based on the example in your link.

Here `12_w` calls `operator "" _w(12ULL)` since there is **a literal operator with the parameter type `unsigned long long`**, while `12_u` calls `operator "" _u("12")` since there is only **a raw literal operator**.

Comment: Can I chose any return type other than unsigned ?

Comment: @ahmedmokhtar Of course, it depends on how you implement it. There is no limitation on return type.